# Using a Mac: Syntax Error when running an app file produced with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, pyinstaller

I ran  pyinstaller --onefile --windowed frontend.py to compile my frontend.py file to produce an app file.  However when I run my dist/frontend file I get the below error:

```
  File "frontend", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcf' in file frontend on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

This is confusing because I'm explicitly declaring frontend.py to use utf-8 encoding:

```
#! /usr/bin/env/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
import backend

#functions
def get_selected_row(event):
    try:
        global selected_tuple
        index= list1.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple=list1.get(index)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0,END)
        e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0,END)
        e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
    except IndexError:
        pass

def view_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.view():
        list1.insert(END, row)

def search_command():
    list1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(),author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()):
        list1.insert(END,row)

def insert_command():
    backend.insert(title_text.get(),author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get())
    list1.delete(0,END)
    list1.insert(END,(title_text.get(),author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()))

def delete_command():
    backend.delete(selected_tuple[0])

def update_command():
    backend.update(selected_tuple[0],title_text.get(),author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get())

window = Tk()

l1=Label(window,text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l1=Label(window,text="Author")
l1.grid(row=0,column=2)

l1=Label(window,text="Year")
l1.grid(row=1,column=0)

l1=Label(window,text="ISBN")
l1.grid(row=1,column=2)

#entries
title_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window,textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

author_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(window,textvariable=author_text)
e2.grid(row=0,column=3)

year_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window,textvariable=year_text)
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)

isbn_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(window,textvariable=isbn_text)
e4.grid(row=1,column=3)

list1=Listbox(window,height=6, width=35)
list1.grid(row=2,column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=2)

sb1=Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=2,column=2,rowspan=6)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

list1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",get_selected_row)

#buttons
b1=Button(window,text="View all",width=12,command=view_command)
b1.grid(row=2,column=3)

b2=Button(window,text="Search entry",width=12,command=search_command)
b2.grid(row=3,column=3)

b3=Button(window,text="Add entry",width=12,command=insert_command)
b3.grid(row=4,column=3)

b4=Button(window,text="Update selected",width=12,command=update_command)
b4.grid(row=5,column=3)

b5=Button(window,text="Delete Selected",width=12,command=delete_command)
b5.grid(row=6,column=3)

b6=Button(window,text="Close",width=12,command=window.destroy)
b6.grid(row=7,column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you showing the file `frontend` ? `\xcf` looks like this `Ï`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I'm showing frontend.py I can't open the frontend app file it gives me this message: "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding".